# Error: System Resource Exceeded

Tags: java, multithreading, ms-access, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

A console application executing under:

```
1). Multiple threads
2). Connection Pooling (as the database connections range could be 5 to 30) of type Microsoft Access using DBCP.
```

While executing this application at my end (not tested the database limit) it works fine. And whenever I try to introduce the same application on one of other machines it generates an error.

I'm wondering why this is happening as there is only the difference of machines here. So, it works perfectly at my end.

I don't know much about connection pooling but it seems whatever I have understood I have implemented as:

```
public class TestDatabases implements Runnable{
    public static Map<String, Connection> correctDatabases;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // validating the databases using DBCP
        datasource.getConnection(); // Obtaining the java.sql.Connection from DataSource
        // if validated successfully  °º¤ø,¸¸,ø¤º°`°º¤ø,¸,ø¤°º¤ø,¸¸,ø¤º°`°º¤ø,¸ putting them in correctDatabases
    }
}
```

The above case is implemented using `ExecutorService` = Number of databases.

Finally, I'm trying to put them in a static Collection of Type 
`Map<String, Connection>` and making use of it throughout the application. In other words: I'm trying to collect the `connectionString` along with the Connection in a Map.

In other parts of my application I'm simply dealing with multiple threads coming along with the Connection URL. So, to perform any database operations I'm calling the

```
Connection con = TestDatabases.correctDatases.get(connectUrl);
```

For that machine, this application works fine for around ~5 databases. And the error is always getting generated when I'm trying to fire the query using above Connection (con) as `stmt.executeQuery(query);`

As, I'm not able to reproduce this issue at my end, it seems something is going-on wrong with the Connection Pooling or I have not configured my application to deal with Connection Pooling correctly.

Just for your information, I'm correctly performing `Connection close` in `finally` block where my application terminates and this Application is using Quartz Scheduler as well. For Connection Pooling, a call to the following from TestDatabases class is done for setUp as:

```
public synchronized DataSource setUp() throws Exception {
    Class.forName(RestConnectionValidator.prop.getProperty("driverClass")).newInstance();
    log.debug("Class Loaded.");
    connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool();
    log.debug("Connection pool made.");
    connectionPool.setMaxActive(100);
    ConnectionFactory cf = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
            RestConnectionValidator.prop.getProperty("connectionUrl")+new String(get().toString().trim()),
            "","");
    PoolableConnectionFactory pcf =
        new PoolableConnectionFactory(cf, connectionPool,
                null, null, false, true);
    return new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);
}
```

Following is the error I'm getting (at the other machine)

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] System resource exceeded.
```

Following is the Database Path:

```
jdbc:odbc:DRIVER= {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\\DataSources\\PR01.mdb
```

Each of those database seems to be not much heavy (its ~ 5 to 15 MB of total size).

So, I'm left with the following solutions:

```
1). Correction of Connection Pooling or migrate to the newer one's like c3p0 or DBPool or BoneCP.
2). Introducing batch concept - in which I will schedule my application for each group of 4 databases. It could be very expensive to deal with as any time the other schedule may also collapse.
```

I’m pretty sure that this is Java related error but I can’t fathom out why.

Comment: Which version of Access drivers do both machines use?  The new machine may need driver updates, such as <http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2726928>  While you say they are small, does the JVM on the new one have less memory allocated?

Comment: Thanks for this! It seems the new machine has some restrictions of updating the drivers as well as most of the Microsoft updates are not doable. I'm now able to somehow reproduce the issues at my end. Does it seem to be the connection management issue? As I'm already using the ConnectionPooling - dbcp.

Answer (score 0):

Just done the migration to BoneCP which solved my problem. I guess due to multi-threaded environment the dpcp was not providing the connection from pool rather it was trying to hit the database again and again. Maybe I could have solved the dpcp issue but migrating to BoneCP also provides advantage of performance.